# Создание туннеля на Linux

Tags: linux, unix, администрирование

Пользуюсь роутером со встроенной возможностью, подключения по PPTP/L2TP
Есть сервер PPTP в зоне C
Я нахожусь в зоне A
Есть под моим контролем сервер в зоне B
Хочется создать туннель A > B > C
На сервере в зоне C PPTP весит на стандартном порте 1723
пытался создать при помощи ssh с опциями -f -L ничего не вышло,роутер не хочет коннектится через созданный туннель.
так же пытался при помощи "socat", создавать командой socat tcp-listen:1723,reuseaddr,fork tcp:server_in_zone_c:1723

хочу чтобы в настройках роутера я прописывал ip адрес сервера в зоне B (который мой), а на выходе я пользовался всемирной сетью через сервер C где стоит PPTP сервер

я так понимаю,что туннель без использования pppd/ pptpd создать не получится? создать http туннель куда проще

Comment: в конечном итоге какую возможность вы хотите получить?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы добавлять ответы, вы можете просто редактировать вопрос. Чуть позже, когда вы наберете 15 репутации (это очень просто), сможете отвечать в комментариях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, товарищ не может или не хочет создать учётную запись и каждый раз заходит анонимно. естественно, у него нет возможности редактировать **чужой** вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: аа. вот даже как...

Comment: Уважаемый автор вопроса. Очень рекомендую вам зарегистрироваться на сайте. Тогда общаться с вами и отвечать на вопрос будет значительно легче.

Comment: и ограничены вы тем, что оба «конца» могут только *pptp*? тогда единственный логичный вывод: 1. подключиться с машины *b* при помощи *pppd* к машине *c*; 2. запустить на машине *b* демона *pptpd*; 3. настроить на машине *b* переброс пакетов между этими двумя туннелями.

Comment: *туннель без использования pppd/ pptpd создать не получится?* — получится, сколько угодно. но **вам же требуется** (по изложенным вами же условиям) ***два*** ppp-туннеля, поверх которых будет работать pptpd: один от вашего роутера до машины *b*, второй от машины *c* до машины *b*.

Answer (score 2):

зарегистрировался на сайте.
частично разобрался в вопросе, пытался создавать туннель socat'ом на сервере от Azure, потом понял, что там передаются только пакеты TCP либо UDP, а PPTP ещё использует GRE протокол, его передачи у Azure не предусматривается, так, что буду пробовать на выделенном сервере. отпишусь о результатах
я так понимаю socat умеет передавать только tcp/udp пакеты,тоесть создать vpn туннель куда проще нежели pptp который использует ещё и gre протокол
есть идеи по решению без использования pptpd??